# Get a list of mailboxes where AD group has permissions

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to get a list of mailboxes that have a an AD group listed in their permissions.
All the AD groups I am interested in start with the same 3 characters.

I have....

```
get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission  | where {$_.user.tostring() -like "xxx*"} | out-file $file -append -noclobber -encoding ascii
```

but it doesn't seem to put anything in the file

What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Andy

Comment: Are you sure that `$_.user.tostring()` doesn't output `domain\UserOrGroup` ? Save the objects in a variable first (without the where-statement) and make sure the string you're matching is what you expect it to be. Also, outputing objects to a text-file like that may not work properly (it depends on the class).

Comment: @FrodeF. The output of that should be `domain\UserOrGroup` I just checked on Exchange 2010

Comment: So what are you trying? You say that all groups start with the same 3 char prefix. Have you tried `.. | where {$_.user.tostring() -like "domain\xxx*"} | ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a sneaking feeling there will be more questions after this but *part* of the issue is you loose the mailbox details when they are being passed into the cmdlet `Get-MailboxPermission`. If you match criteria was a little more refined your output would just be the groups that matched but not to which mailbox.

```powershell
$file = "c:\temp\test.csv"
$matchPrefix = [regex]::Escape("Ex") # We use escape incase of special charaters in regex. Period would be one to expect.
$regex = "YOURDOMAIN\\$matchPrefix" # Keep those backslashes
Get-Mailbox mc* | ForEach-Object{
    $results = $_ | Get-MailboxPermission | Where-Object{$_.User.ToString() -match $regex}
    If($results){$_}    
} | Select Name,Alias | Export-CSV $file -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

This will take every mailbox and check each for the presence of the group/user. Using `$regex` we check each of the located user/groups. If they are present then the `-match` would return True satisfying the Where block and the mailbox is passed in the pipeline to be exported.

For the export we just send the mailbox name and alias to a csv file specified by `$file`

**Caveats**

`-Append` is available in PowerShell 3.0 which you exchange might not have. I could just be removed.

**Assumptions**

I am assuming you want just the mailboxes that match the group prefix you specify. If you want the actual groups that match it is possible with a little extra logic. I would like to know if what I suggest is sufficient before I guess more.

Comment: I ran the script as above (changing the details to match my environment) and got an error about running consecutive pipeline not being allowed.

Comment: @MoriteUK Sorry about that. Will address that concern. What about the return? Do you just want the matching mailboxes?

Comment: @MoriteUK. See my updated answer. Nesting the `where`'s was not required and some slight changes were made.

Answer (score 0):

This code works, and it is also clear as to which mailbox these permissions belong:

```
get-mailbox -resultsize 1000 | foreach{
Write-Host $_.PrimarySMTPAddress -ForegroundColor Green;
$permissions = Get-MailboxPermission $_.PrimarySMTPAddress | ?{$_.User -match "Ryan"}
if($permissions){
    $permissions | FT -AutoSize;
    $_.PrimarySmtpAddress | Out-File C:\Test.txt -append -noclobber -encoding ascii; 
    $permissions | FT -AutoSize | Out-File C:\Test.txt -append -noclobber -encoding ascii;
}
```

}

Please note: I checked to see what $_.user.tostring() produces in order to know what I am looking for with respect to the "match" Boolean logic.

Comment: Don't double answer. In most cases you there is not reason. Also I dont think the op just wants a list of matching groups since that gives no information about the mailboxes that matched

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to posting here and I didn't see a way to post format-able code in a comment. Further, my code does exactly what he wants (except I pointed it to just one mailbox for testing), and the code does work the way it is intended. If he wants to know more information, then I would throw a Select statement in there just before the Out-File and choose what you want to write to the file.

Comment: This works, and is clear as to which mailbox these permissions belong:

get-mailbox -resultsize 1000 | foreach{
    Write-Host $_.PrimarySMTPAddress -ForegroundColor Green;
    $permissions = Get-MailboxPermission $_.PrimarySMTPAddress | ?{$_.User -match "Ryan"}
    if($permissions){
        $permissions | FT -AutoSize;
        $_.PrimarySmtpAddress | Out-File C:\Test.txt -append -noclobber -encoding ascii; 
        $permissions | FT -AutoSize | Out-File C:\Test.txt -append -noclobber -encoding ascii;
    }
}